# MS ChatBot - ClientConnector unauthorized exception

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot

I'm trying to send a proactive message from an Azure function using ConnectorClient, but I'm getting an authorized exception despite using the correct `AppId` & `AppPassword`

```
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(queueMessage.ChatBotDetails.ServiceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials(appId, appPassword));

await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```

But this is generating the following exception:

`Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'`

I am outputting the app password and app Id in the logs and they are correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to add this call before calling the connector client:

`MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(queueMessage.ChatBotDetails.ServiceUrl);`